# Ajax call not working in ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I created an empty ASP.NET website and created an ajax call the returns Hello World.  I then created an ASP.net web application.  The same exact ajax call that is working fine in the empty website does not work in the web application.  I was wondering why that is.

Comment: We can't possibly know without any information about the error or any code which produces the error.

Comment: Why not edit your post and show us the code of both your website and your main ASP.net page, and also provide the text of any errors that occur, that would help us to establish better what is happening and provide an explanation.

Comment: Thanks guys.  It's just an extremely simple ajax call that works fine in the empty website.  In the web application I don't get any errors.  It actually runs the ajax success function but doesn't run the webmethod in the code behind.  I'm thinking that the web application forces you to use a generic httphandler in the .ashx page, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  A line in the RegisterRoutes method had to commented out.  In the web application the App_Code folder contains a RouteConfig.cs class.  This can also be found in the App_Start folder.  In the web application it simply wasn't interpreting the url in my ajax call correctly.  In the empty website there is no built in routing so it wasn't an issue there.

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
       // settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```