# How to call .Net webform method from Html ( using jQuery ajax )

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, webforms

I've a .Net Web form project like below . [image]

I want to call this GetData Method From my Html- Jquery  in a button click

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:49313/WebForm.aspx/GetData/",
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
```

But I'm getting error like below . pls let me what are the configurations I've to add

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:49313/WebForm.aspx/GetData/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Answer (score 1):

First, even when not sending data, I recommend that you always use POST. Get tends to suggest and "imply" you're calling a REST end point.

So, for your code to work, you need to tag/set the routine (in fact a method of the web page in question) to static.

So, you need this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetDate()
    {
        return "Hellow how are you";
    }
```

So, you need to define that routine as a webmethod.

And you thus find you need:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

And now the sample looks like this:

```
        function mytest() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GuageTest2.aspx/GetData",
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (MyReturnData) {

                    alert("Return data = " + MyReturnData.d)

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                    alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                }
            });
```

Note VERY closely, you have to use ".d" to get that return value (it's a .net thing, and I believe was a security issue, but ".d" is how you get the return value).

Say you wanted to return several values?

Then I often just shove right into the code behind for that page a class right into the code.

Say this:

```
    public class MyStatInfo
    {
        public int TotalFiles = 0;
        public int PdfFiles = 0;
        public int ZipFiles = 0;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static MyStatInfo GetData()
    {
        MyStatInfo MyData= new MyStatInfo();
        MyData.TotalFiles = 100;
        MyData.PdfFiles = 75;
        MyData.ZipFiles = 25;
        return MyData;
    }
```

And now the JS code is this:

```
                success: function (MyStats) {

                    var TotalFiles = MyStats.d.TotalFiles
                    var PdfFiles = MyStats.d.PdfFiles
                    var ZipFiles = MyStats.d.ZipFiles

  ... do whatever with the value(s)
```

Again, note the use of ".d" to get the data returned.

Comment: Hi @Albert But I'm getting the same issue like "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:49313/WebForm.aspx/GetData/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: You have to post the code, we don't know what you have.  check out this post if you are using friednly URL's and thus change routeconfig (assuming you are using). Also, don't include the http://LocalHost but JUST  WebForms.aspx/GetData in the url for the ajax call. (no trailing "/" here). so check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465494/ajax-call-not-working-in-asp-net-web-application